# R: get Error in `contrasts<- when using combn and mapply

Tags: r, combinations, apply

Right now, I have a script where I would like to get the difference in HeartBeats for all the combinations of people in my datasheet. I tried combining them and then calling the function but I get the error message

```
Error in `contrasts<-`(`*tmp*`, value = contr.funs[1 + isOF[nn]])
```

I'm wondering what the error is. I tried following a similar post on Stack Overflow, but I couldn't get it to work for my script.

```
rm(list=ls())
data <- read.csv("C:\\Users\\tctech\\Desktop\\HearBeatData.csv")

attach(data)

symbols_v <- c('James', 'Sara', 'Teegan', 'Logan', 'Tia')

f <- function(x, y) 
{
slope <- lm(x ~ y)
beta <- summary(slope)$coefficients[2, 1]
diff <- (x - beta*y)
}

out <- combn(symbols_v, 2)
mapply(f, out[1,], out[2,])
```

Comment: Could you reproduce this error with a built in dataset?

Comment: I'll give that a try to see if it's not my dataset that is wrong

Comment: Cool. The other reason to do this is that if you make your example reproducible then it's a lot easier for people like me to help you troubleshoot.